# Crash when opening - neo4j 3.1.2 Community Edition

Tags: neo4j

I am totally new to neo4j. I have downloaded de software and installed it, but when I open it, it crashes immediately.

Below is the error I get. I have shorten the error text because its incredibly long.

Any ideas? I tried to reinstall, restart etc. but no luck.

Thank you in advance,

Cristina

```
>Process:               JavaApplicationStub [877]
Path:                  /Applications/Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.2.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
Identifier:            com.install4j.8478-6373-2628-9929.24
Version:               3.1.2 (3.1.2)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           JavaApplicationStub [877]
User ID:               502

>Date/Time:             2017-03-28 13:43:24.705 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        9E54842F-ADA5-86BD-C792-F5A255A236CE


>Time Awake Since Boot: 760 seconds

>Crashed Thread:        0  AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main->thread

>Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
>Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000303620

>VM Regions Near 0x303620:
>--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-000000010000a000 [   40K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Neo4j Community Edition 3.1.2.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub

>Application Specific Information:
abort() called

>Thread 0 Crashed:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff937d2286 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff94d9a9b3 abort + 129
2   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104482beb os::abort(bool) + 25
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001045a6a2a VMError::report_and_die() + 2304
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104484816 JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000104480a7b signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff8b907f1a _sigtramp + 26
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff94d3dfb2 strlen + 18
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff942c8a3c __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8524
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff943be3a0 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 256
10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff973f5701 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 153
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9740eef9 +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 174
12  com.apple.java.JavaRuntimeSupport   0x000000011c276fce -[JRSInputMethodController availableInputMethodLocales] + 253
13  libawt_lwawt.dylib              0x000000011d21907f __Java_sun_lwawt_macosx_CInputMethodDescriptor_nativeGetAvailableLocales_block_invoke_1 + 124
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9747ddd0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 293
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9430aa01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff942fcb8d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff942fc1bf __CFRunLoopRun + 927
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff942fbbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d1cf56f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d1cf2ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8d1cf12b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92a118ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92a10e58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
24  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000011cf6a3aa -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 124
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff92a06af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
26  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000011cf6a14d +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 156
27  libawt_lwawt.dylib              0x000000011d23f517 -[AWTStarter starter:] + 905
28  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9747ddd0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 293
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff9430aa01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
30  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff942fcb8d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
31  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff942fc1bf __CFRunLoopRun + 927
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff942fbbd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
33  com.oracle.java.8u60.jdk        0x00000001000f28fb CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871
34  com.oracle.java.8u60.jdk        0x00000001000ee644 JLI_Launch + 1952
35  com.install4j.8478-6373-2628-9929.24    0x0000000100006cf4 -[Launcher launch] + 836
36  com.install4j.8478-6373-2628-9929.24    0x0000000100007381 launcher_main + 625
37  com.install4j.8478-6373-2628-9929.24    0x00000001000074f2 main + 34
38  com.install4j.8478-6373-2628-9929.24    0x0000000100001154 start + 52
```

Comment: Easiest way to fix this is to download the tar version and just unzip it and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by a crash in `[JRSInputMethodController availableInputMethodLocales]`, which is related to the relatively old version of OSX that you're using (10.10.5).

It's ultimately a problem inside the version of Java that Apple ships with that OS version, and according to [this post](https://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2015/Sep/msg00006.html), the issue was fixed in 10.11.

That post also suggests that you can use the Java SE 6 installer [found here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US), which supposedly contains a fix for the problem.

FWIW, you're not the only one with this problem, there is an (as yet unresolved) issue for Neo4j posted [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/8555).

Comment: Thank you so much!